# Could not find a suitable SDK to target, tried everything

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, uwp, enterprise

I tried downloading "Visual Studio Enterprise 2015" throw Visual studio and everything working but the UWP, whenever I try to start a new/old UWP project, it giives me the "Could not find a suitable SDK to target." message box, I've already tried:
- Modify Visual Studio and add the UWP sdk - gives me an error (-2146889721 or 2005)
- Installing the Windows 10 sdk - throw that [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and it gives me that error: ""Error information: Unable to verify the integriity of downloaded content. It might be corrupted. Please check your internet connection and try again".
I have tried everything I could find online, but nothing seems to help, what to do?

Comment: Please try to troubleshot by [this document](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-performance/windows-10-performance-and-install-integrity/75529fd4-fac7-4653-893a-dd8cd4b4db00)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your SDK target for this project.

If your project is loaded but unavailable right-click on project and select edit project.json. Change target from some "10240" to your SDK installed for example "14393" (if you have anniversary update). Save and right-click your project select Reload.

Should work if it's your case.

Comment: It won't let me, it writes (for example): "App8 (update required)", and that's only when I'm opening one, if I try to open a new one it says that he could not find a suitable SDK,

Comment: btw, UWP is working at Visual Studio Community when I tried to use it, but I want to use the enterprise, in Community is working fine